# Refreshing a region with a condition

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an apex page that has some search items filled by the user. One of these items is a check-box with 4 values used to search. For example, 4 check-boxes(but only 1 item) with the values A:B:C:D. I have 4 reports(one for each check-box value), that must be showed only in case of the corresponding check-box is marked. So, I put a SQL condition in each report, ex: for report 1, condition => :P324_MY_CHECKBOX like '%A%', for report 2, condition => :P324_MY_CHECKBOX like '%B%' ...

When user fill the form, he clicks on "Search" button that invokes a dynamic action. This DA sets the items on the session and refresh the 4 reports. The expected result would be to show only some regions, according to the selected check-boxes. The problem is that the condition doesn't work in this case of refresh. I can see in the apex session that the item P324_MY_CHECKBOX doesn't has the value "A" for example but the corresponding report is still showed.

Resuming, the condition of region doesn't work(is not re-evaluated) if I refresh the region in a Dynamic Action.

Has anyone had this kind of problem? Is there an expert or guru to help me?

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 1):

Conditions are evaluated on render of the page while dynamic actions are javascript commands that operate on the rendered page.

Instead show all regions without conditions and control the hide/show using your dynamic action.

Comment: Thank you ScottWe, I did like you mentioned and now it's working. I had to remove the conditions in my reports and to control using dynamic actions. I put static id's on my regions so I can now use Javascript functions to show($x_Show('myReport')) or hide($x_Hide('myReport')) my reports depending on user choices. I chose to use Javascript code to do this but I could also use actions like Show/Hide/Refresh. However, in this case I would have to create one dynamic action for each report because of the conditions are not applied for True/False Actions.

Comment: I came back and I created one Dynamic Action for each report. I prefer to avoid using Javascript code when it's possible and instead I put the logic of hiding/refreshing my reports in Dynamic Actions by using the True/False actions.

Thank you again! Have a nice day!